# delete the entire row in a file if first column is repeated and save modified data into another file

Tags: shell

I have data like below

```
abcd eeee
efgh eeee
wxyz njtq
abcd rtmk
ijkl mnmn
wxyz mnmn
```

I need output as

```
abcd eeee,rtmk
efgh eeee
wxyz njtq,mnmn
ijkl mnmn
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F" " '{if(a[$1]){a[$1]=a[$1]","$2} else { a[$1]=$2}} END {for (i in a) {print i" "a[i]}}' inputfile
```

Explanation: split based on space and check if first column matches then add to the list of second columns separated by `,`s and then print results from `inputfile` which contains the data.

Comment: While it is nice to help with a problem, you should discourage questions that ask you to "Code it for me". That is one of the purposes behind [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the help.But unfortunately I am not getting the expected output. I am getting below output which is incorrect. can you please suggest me in this                                                                        ,rtmkeeee                                                                                                                                                     
efgh eeee
ijkl mnmn
,mnmnnjtq